# How to save and load my array in plist? What's wrong with my code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, plist

I'm newbie in Objective-C, I'm learning it.
Now I'm trying to solve the problem to save and load my array from plist after app's restart.
Thanks a lot for the answers.
Now I have the following code, that still doesn't work.

First of all I get the path to plist:

```
//get the path to plist-file
- (NSString *)getPathToPlist
{
    @try
    {
        DDLogVerbose(@"getPathToPlist method has been started...");

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);   //create a list of paths
        //NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];                                             //get a path to your documents directory from the list
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];                                             //get a path to your documents directory from the list
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BGMToDoItems.plist"];               //create a full file path

        DDLogVerbose(@"getPathToPlist method has been completed. Your path is: %@", path);

        return path;
    }
    @catch(NSException *exception) //catch the exception
    {
        DDLogError(@"Error! Something is wrong in getPathToPlist method. Catching %@ reason %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
    }

}
```

After this I have two methods. One for save my array to plist:

```
//save array to plist
- (void)plistSave
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"plistSave method has been started...");

    //get the path to plist-file
    NSString *path = [self getPathToPlist];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
    //save toDoItems to file
    @try
    {

        [self.toDoItems writeToFile:path atomically: YES];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        DDLogError(@"Error! Something is wrong while toDoItems array was saving (plistSave method). Catching %@ reason %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
    }

    DDLogVerbose(@"Your plist successfully saved."); 
}
```

And the other one for load:

```
//initialization of the toDoItems array (load from plist or initial creation)
- (void) plistArrayLoad: (NSString *)path
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"plistArrayLoad method has been started with path param %@...", path);

    //check the plist existing
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) //if plist doesn't exist
    {
        DDLogVerbose(@"Your plist file doesn't exist, so I'll create one...");

        //create the plist file in your documents directory from the bundle directory (by XCode)
        @try
        {
            NSError *error;

            NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BGMToDoItems" ofType:@"plist"]; //get the path to your plist created before in bundle directory (by XCode)
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error];                                //copy plist to your documents directory
            DDLogVerbose(@"Plist file successfully created.");

            //load the default array as ToDoItems to memory
            self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //memory allocation
            [self defaultArrayFill];                        //fill in the array with default items
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            DDLogError(@"Error! Something is wrong while plist init (plistArrayLoad method). Catching %@ reason %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
        }
    }
    else //if user's plist exist
    {
        @try
        {
            DDLogVerbose(@"Your plist file exist. Your toDoItems array is loading from %@...", path);

            //self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //memory allocation
            self.toDoItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

            DDLogVerbose(@"Your toDoItems array successfully loaded.");
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            DDLogError(@"Error! Something is wrong while toDoItems array was loading (plistArrayLoad method). Catching %@ reason %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
        }
    }

}
```

When I have the first run my "IF" works like "plist doesn't exist" and everything is OK, I see the "defaultArrayFill" in my UITableView. I can edit it.
But at the second run, when my "IF" works like plist exist. I see a clear table without any data... All logs are correct I see start and end of each method which have to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Help me please. I apologize but I'm learning it my first code topic on stackoverflow

Thanks a lot for the answers.

Comment: Can you add the exact exception message ?

Comment: You could try saving in to the `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` since it will take an array.  If there are problems at that point then the data you are trying to save isn't good(like maybe a block or something else fun)

Comment: *Not related to your problem per se*: The line with the comment "memory allocation" does indeed allocate a new empty `NSMutableArray`; however the following line throws that array away and instead store a reference to a *different* array. You should review your understanding of how object allocation works. HTH. *(As others have already requested, more info is required to help diagnose your exception problem.)*

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've changed my code like insane-36 said. Now I don't have the exceptions... But I don't see changes in my array after app's restart. :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be mistake in your method where you create the path. If you log the path then you will find that it is not what you expect. Use stringByAppendingPathComponent: to add the filename to create the full path.

```
 - (NSString *)getPathToPlist
{
    @try
    {
         DDLogVerbose(@"getPathToPlist method has been started...");

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);   //create a list of paths
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BGMToDoItems.plist"];               //create a full file path

       DDLogVerbose(@"getPathToPlist method has been completed. Your path is: %@", path);

       return path;
    }
    @catch(NSException *exception) //catch the exception
    {
        DDLogError(@"Error! Something is wrong in getPathToPlist method. Catching %@ reason %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);

    }
}

- (void) plistArrayLoad: (NSString *)path
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"Your plist file exist. Your toDoItems array is loading from %@...", path);

   self.toDoItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

   DDLogVerbose(@"Your toDoItems array successfully loaded.");   
}

- (void)plistSave
{
     DDLogVerbose(@"plistSave method has been started...");
    NSString *path = [self getPathToPlist];
    NSLog(@"path %@", path);
    [self.toDoItems writeToFile:path atomically: YES];
    DDLogVerbose(@"Your plist successfully saved."); 

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
Ok. Now I don't get the exception... But I don't see changes in my array after app's restart. :( Any ideas?
And what the deference between mine [paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString an yours [paths firstObject]; stringByAppendingPathComponent? The result must be same...

Comment: Did you know that firstObject method to array is there. It is the same as [paths objectAtIndex:0]. You appended the path component directly using stringByAppendingString: @"BGMToDoItems.plist", but it should be stringByAppendingString: @"/BGMToDoItems.plist" if you use this method. The method I used, stringByAppendingPathComponent: adds slashes automatically.

Comment: Are you sure your array has content in it and the saved changes do not show ? You could browse the file system in your mac and see if the plist is written correctly and has all the objects you inserted.

Comment: You're right I don't see the plist file, but if it's so why my log says: "2014-03-04 19:47:34:748 [14489:70b] Your plist successfully saved."? :((

Comment: I put some code to save like 
if([self.toDoItems writeToFile:path atomically: YES]){
        NSLog(@"+++");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"---");
    };
And I get --- in the log...

Comment: Could it be that you have your array nil ?

Comment: Log the array before you actually save it to see what you have been saving.

Comment: My array is binding to TableView and I see it.
Ok. I tried to print it here the log:
2014-03-04 20:13:33.083 I Do My Best[15303:70b] Received memory warning.
2014-03-04 20:13:33.085 I Do My Best[15303:70b] ---
2014-03-04 20:13:33.085 I Do My Best[15303:70b] (
    "<BGMToDoItem: 0x8ba58f0>",
    "<BGMToDoItem: 0x8ba5930>",
    "<BGMToDoItem: 0x8ba5950>",
    "<BGMToDoItem: 0x8ba5970>"
)
2014-03-04 20:13:33:084 I Do My Best[15303:70b] plistSave method has been started...
Yes, my array has four lines. The only thing that strange why first "---" and then "plistSave method has been started..."

Comment: Damn, is it because the array consists with my custom objects BGMToDoItem? If so why did exception didn't tell me about that :(( How can I learn if exception doesn't help with so stupid errors :(

Comment: Keep a break point in xcode to see where the exception actually occurs. If you are saving the Objects inside array then use NSCoding protocol to save to plist file

Comment: So, am I right? The problem is inside my custom objects BGMToDoItem in array that I try to save to plist?

Answer (score 0):

When generating your path try using

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BGMToDoItems.plist"];
```

instead of

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"BGMToDoItems.plist"];
```

this will automatically add a slash between the components. The way you are doing it now the app would try to create the file `DocumentsBGMToDoItems.plist` in the parent directory to wich you don´t have write permissions.

Also you probably should use

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
```

to delete the file before you save the new one as `writeToFile:` does not overwrite existing files.

Comment: I tried but with same result. And I thought that I get the exception if I'll try to overwrite the file... But now I've returned removeItemAtPath. Thanks!
Anyway, I'm confused. Why I cannot save changes in my array. I think that I made a stupid mistake, but how to find it :(

Answer (score 0):

About the exceptions: Objective-C isn't Java. You throw exceptions for programming errors. You don't catch them, you fix the code. Your trying to catch exceptions only means your program may run into trouble and mess things up.

For example, getPathToPlist won't even return a result if it catches an exception.

Comment: So, does your word mean that my exceptions are useless in Objective-C? And I don't need to put every method in @try/@catch. 
I used to do it in C#... I know maybe it isn't a good way but I saw an errors in my code and it was a way for understand my errors and learn what I did wrong without any help.